# Excel Crash when sorting grouped columns

Tags: excel, sorting, crash, grouping

I have an Excel Sheet which crashes regularly. You'll find it attached at the end.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Filter Column 2 skipping empty rows (just 'a' and 'b' are selected)
2. Sort Column 2 from A to Z
3. Excel will crash

If I drop the grouping (Data-->Group) sorting works fine. It also works fine when grouping the columns instead of the rows.

There exists a similar bug report:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50314
But my worksheet.xml is alright.

Do you have any ideas how I can prevent Excel from crashing without surrendering the grouping?

OS: Win7 Enterprise SP1 64bit

Office: Professional Plus 2010

File: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8384127/Minimal-Example.xlsx.html

Comment: How do you specification differ from mine? (Os, Office)

Comment: Office Professional Plus 2010, Win7 Professional SP1 x64. Still as it seems your problem is neither caused by custom functionality like formulas or macros but by some standard-functionality you're maybe better off with contacting office support.